# Specifying an alias to column names in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am currently querying the auth_users table of django to return the users which matched the search criteria.

```
users = User.objects.filter(
      Q(first_name__icontains = name)| 
      Q(username__icontains = name) | 
      Q(email__icontains = name) | 
      Q(last_name__icontains = name)
   ).values(
      'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
   ).order_by('first_name')
```

I was wondering if it's possible for me to change the name of 'first_name' to 'firstname'?
like we can do in SQL [`Select first_name as firstname from auth_users`];

so that I can access it by using firstname instead of first_name

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: There is a legacy javascript code which is using different field names so I was thinking of renaming the columns to the ones which it refers to for the users object.

Answer (score 9):

You can annotate the fields as you want, with the [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F

users = User.objects.filter(
      Q(first_name__icontains = name) | 
      Q(username__icontains = name) | 
      Q(email__icontains = name) | 
      Q(last_name__icontains = name)
   ).values(
      'id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email'
   ).order_by('first_name'
   ).annotate(firstname = F('first_name'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a translation layer between the two namespaces. Since you are using the Django ORM and the JavaScript code is legacy I would assume you would want to do this in Python.

```
def translate(js_column_name):
    return {
        'firstname': 'first_name',
    }.get(js_column_name, 'string to return when not found')
```

Using this translation function you could create the keyword arguments in a dictionary and then pass that to the `Q` function using `**`:

```
User.objects.filter(
    Q(**{
        translate(js_firstname) + '_icontains': name
    }) ...
```

Of course I assume that you would not know the input you are translating is `'firstname'` otherwise you could just define the correct column names without needing a function to do it (i.e. just create your query as normal). So instead I assume you are receiving the JavaScript column names dynamically in which case this approach is what I would use.

P.S. I hope this best answers your question. In future I would advise you provide a context for your problem (i.e. specify that you have this problem because..., and that the javascript names appear dynamically etc.). This way your question will get answered more quickly.