# Alias Name in Query Set

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm using following code set to pull data from specific columns of the table...

```
cityList = City.objects.using(settings.DATABASE_CONF).filter(
    status=1).values('city_name_en', 'city_id')
```

How can I set an alias for the `city_name_en` column? I have two other columns with `city_name_fr` `city_name_de` but the client can understand only `city_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think giving alias in Django query is not possible. However you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190886/specifying-an-alias-to-column-names-in-django).

Answer (score 3):

You can annotate the fields as you want, with the [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F

cityList = City.objects.using(settings.DATABASE_CONF).filter(status=1).values(
    'city_name_en', 'city_id')
# use F expression to annotate with an alias
cityList = cityList.annotate(cityname=F('city_name_en'))
```