# How to convert SQL states below to Django ORM

Tags: python, sql, django, django-orm

Having difficult time to convert the SQL statements below to Django ORM. Any help is much appreciated.

```
SELECT a.state, 
       a.city, 
       a.postcode, 
       b.rate_authority, 
       b.rate, 
       b.rate_descr 
FROM   fileload_taxratemodel AS a 
       INNER JOIN fileload_taxrateresponsemodel AS b 
               ON b.jurs_id_id = a.id 
ORDER  BY state ASC
```

**Django Models:**

Trying to pull fields from both model based on the foreign key.

```
class TaxRateModel(models.Model):

company_code = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
document_date = models.DateTimeField()
country = models.CharField(max_length = 30, default = "US")
province = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null= True,blank= True)
state = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
county = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length = 100,blank=True, null=True)
district = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, null=True)
postcode = models.CharField(max_length = 5, blank=True, null=True)
rate_code = models.CharField(max_length = 30,default = "ST")
```

Django 2nd Model :

```
class TaxRateResponseModel(models.Model):
jurs_id = models.ForeignKey(TaxRateModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='rates')
rate_authority = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, null=True, default='')
rate_descr = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, null=True, default ='')
rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits= 10, decimal_places=5)
```

Comment: can you add your django models ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have these models inside a django app called `horaire`:

```
class A(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)


class B(models.Model):
    jurs_id = models.ForeignKey(A, related_name="ab", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    rate_authority = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    rate = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    rate_descr = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

In your django's shell you can do:

```
$> from horaire.models import B
$> items = B.objects.values(
       'jurs_id__city',
       'jurs_id__state',
       'jurs_id__postcode',
       'rate_authority',
       'rate',
       'rate_descr'
   ).order_by('jurs_id__state')
$> print(items.query)
SELECT 
    "horaire_a"."city", 
    "horaire_a"."state", 
    "horaire_a"."postcode",
    "horaire_b"."rate_authority",
    "horaire_b"."rate",
    "horaire_b"."rate_descr" 
FROM "horaire_b" 
    INNER JOIN "horaire_a" ON ("horaire_b"."jurs_id_id" = "horaire_a"."id") 
ORDER BY "horaire_a"."state" ASC
```

OR, you can do:

```
$> from horaire.models import A
$> items = A.objects.values(
       'city',
       'postcode',
       'state',
       'ab__rate_authority',
       'ab__rate',
       'ab__rate_descr'
   ).order_by('state')
$> print(items.query)
SELECT 
    "horaire_a"."city", 
    "horaire_a"."postcode", 
    "horaire_a"."state", 
    "horaire_b"."rate_authority", 
    "horaire_b"."rate", 
    "horaire_b"."rate_descr" 
FROM "horaire_a" 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "horaire_b" ON ("horaire_a"."id" = "horaire_b"."jurs_id_id") 
ORDER BY "horaire_a"."state" ASC
```

However as you can see, there is not any `ALIAS` in the final SQL queries and i didn't find a relative way to make it happen using `DJANGO ORM` (see this [answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230691/alias-name-in-query-set)).
Besides of this, you can alway pass a `Raw SQL` and of course you can write you custom SQL query and you can later consume the data under your applications.
For more informations about `Raw SQL in Django`, visit this [documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/sql/)

Comment: awesome @chiheb, thats exactly what i was looking for - thanks so much!!